# Update the Bing map based on new coordinate in realtime

Tags: coordinates, real-time, gis, updates, bing-maps

Goal:
Update the visual position in bing map.

Problem:
If I add new latitude and logitude coordinate in the textbox, the bing should be displayed but it doesn't work.

Info:
*You need to use your own api key code.
*---http://jsbin.com/zegimofege/edit?html,console,output

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Reference to the Bing Maps SDK -->
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[your kep]' 
            async defer></script>
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap()
    {
  var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
   credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
   mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,   
   center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseInt(document.getElementById("log")), parseInt(document.getElementById("lat"))),
   zoom: 10
  });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
  
  <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
 
  Log: <input type="text" id="log" value="51.50632"><br>
  Lat: <input type="text" id="lat" value="-0.12714"><br>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added no code to do anything when the text box values are updated. Add events to them. Which event you use is up to you, some to consider, keyup, unfocus, or add an update button. In the event handler, get these values and convert to floats using parseFloat, then set the map view like this map.setView({ center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon) })

Comment: Thank you for your help!